# Правильное расположение папок в корневом каталоге сайта

Tags: php, mvc

Просматриваю видеоурок по php. Так вот там структура сайта такова, что папки Контроллера, Модели, Представления и пр. расположены не в www/ , а на уровень выше, т.е. по соседству с www/. Такая реализация возможна вообще?

Comment: конечно, причем это позволяет приложение держать одно, а сайтов с разными настройками  несколько. *завязывайте с видеоуроками - то что за 1 минуту прочитаешь, 20 минут в видео смотреть будешь*

Comment: ))) Наверное поэтому я и задаю здесь вопросы.
Скажите, я так понял, что такое расположение папок гарантирует 100% защиту? Ведь попасть из браузера в такую папку невозможно.

Comment: @eicto, к тому же в этих уроках настаивают, чтобы php-скрипт был без закрывающего тэга `?>`. Что бы это значило?

Comment: это ничего не гарантирует, если у вас дыра в скрипте, то зайти в такую директорию несложно. **без закрывающего тега - правильно** т.к. это позволяет избежать поиска пустых строк в концах файлов, что часто приводит к *headers already sent*